# Constant defined by PHP define() really global?

Tags: php

I just define a root path as a constant like this

```
define("ROOT_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
```

so, at the same file, they can recognize ROOT_PATH, however, in the other file, ROOT_PATH is null, I check some forums, people said defined constant can be use in global, however, I can't, is that I need to do some config in PHP.ini?

Actually, why I do that is because I'm moving the site to new server, however, the new server seems don't like me use relative path, therefore, I need to change to absolute path.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks everyone, I think I catch the reason, I use ajax to call the file, so the ROOT_PATH is null, therefore, I define ROOT_PATH in every file, but another problem is appear, my file structure is sth like this

```
/index.php
/ajax/a1.php
/inc/inc.php

index.php:
<?
define('ROOT_PATH',dirname(__FILE__));
include_once ROOT_PATH."/inc/inc.php";
?>


a1.php:
<?
define('ROOT_PATH',dirname(__FILE__));
include_once ROOT_PATH."/inc/inc.php";
?>
```

so, when the client side call a1.php, it will include inc.php, however, it doesn't like what I imagine, I get this from the chrome developer tools

```
<b>Warning</b>:  include_once(D:\.............\ajax/inc/a1.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>D:\..................\inc\inc.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
```

I check with the ROOT_PATH generated by both file, find that, **FILE** is depends on the caller,

if index.php call it, the

```
ROOT_PATH = d:\.............\
```

if a1.php call it, the

```
ROOT_PATH = d:\..............\ajax\
```

however, both file I need to call that file, any method can I overcome this? thanks.

SOLVED:

Hi, I just figure out how to over come the path problem, first of all, we need to setup a file in every directory, and this file store the absolute path information refer to the relative path(hard to understand? :P), I call this file `path.php`, for my example

```
/index.php
/ajax/a1.php
/inc/inc.php
```

therefore, we need to add 3 path.php in this 3 directroy, as follow,

```
/index.php
/path.php
/ajax/a1.php
/ajax/path.php
/inc/inc.php
/inc/path.php
```

each setting of the `path.php` like this,

`/path.php`

```
 <?

if(!defined(ROOT_PATH))
    define(ROOT_PATH, dirname(__FILE__));

?>
```

`/ajax/path.php` & `/inc/path.php`

```
<?

if(!defined(ROOT_PATH))
    define(ROOT_PATH, '..');

?>
```

so, if we have a 3 leve structure, let say: `/one/two/`, then the `/one/two/path.php` should be like this

```
<?

if(!defined(ROOT_PATH))
    define(ROOT_PATH, '../..');

?>
```

After we set up all this file, we need to include this `path.php` as follow, for example with `index.php`

`/index.php`

```
<?

include_once "path.php";
include_once ROOT_PATH."/inc/inc.php";

...
?>
```

So, whoever the caller is, it will first include the local `path.php`, and find out the relative path `(/ or .. or ../..)`, therefore, the included file will not be wrong because all of them are include with correct symbol, let say,

if caller is /index.php, then ROOT_PATH = "FULLPATH", so

```
include_once ROOT_PATH."/inc/inc.php";
=
include_once "FULLPATH"."/inc/inc.php";
```

if caller is /ajax/a1.php, then ROOT_PATH = "..", so

```
include_once ROOT_PATH."/inc/inc.php";
=
include_once ".."."/inc/inc.php";
```

Comment: Do you include the php script, that contains the `define()` statement, into you second script?

Comment: ... or do you include your second script into the script that define() the constant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what "global" means.

A constant is available in a script, from the point you define it until the end of the script, including in the context of any scripts `include`d or `require`d inside it.

It's not magically available in other, unrelated scripts on your webserver.

---

**Update**

So you're trying to obtain the path to your webroot from any arbitrary file underneath it.

Of course `__FILE__` won't work, as an individual file knows only its own path, and not how far down the directory structure it is.

You could try this:

In `utility.php`:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
```

In `somedir/somefile.php`:

```
require_once "../utility.php";
echo ROOT_PATH;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I misunderstanding the global means, please see my update.

Answer (score 4):

Constant are superglobals, once [define](http://it.php.net/define)d , you can use them without using the keyword *global* to import it into the current scope.

Once you define a constant it is available into the current file (from the definition onward) and into the required/included files that are included after the constant definition.

This is all. You can't access to the constant into a different file if the file is not
included into the defining one or if the defining file is not included into the file you
you need to access the constant.

Comment: First sentence is misleading. "Global at file level" would be something that you could use anywhere in a file where it is defined (after it is defined), but it could not be used in linked/included files.

Answer (score 3):

Such defines really are global. You are probably using `ROOT_PATH` before you are defining it. Turn on error reporting and check the order of your includes.

Answer (score 1):

The primary definition of `define()` and other pages does not tell about constants being scoped at any way:

- http://www.php.net/define
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php